# How Meta Stack Overflow is different with Meta Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion

If I have a question like," How does XYZ work? ", Where should I ask or post this question?  I was bit confused as in stack overflow and stack meta exchange, both are having same hint in ask question text box.

Answer (score 2):

Meta Stack Overflow is specifically for the Stack Overflow site. If you want ask about Meta SE, you can ask here on Meta SE. Though you should clarify your question. See the *How to Ask* boxes on the page for posting questions:

[image] [image]

On Meta sites, though, you can get away with questions that can just be discussed.

Comment: Sorry I took this question in general, but i was bit confused as in stack overflow and stack meta exchange, both are having same hint in ask question text box..

Comment: @ArjunSingh because they are both meta sites. All meta sites have the same hint. Look at the *How to Ask* box next to it, instead.